# Multiple Model binding on route slug url

Tags: laravel, model-binding

I have 2 Model: **Category** and **Product**, category model has a hasToMany relationship with Product and product has belongsTo relation with the category. My route is /sports/some-slug-sports-article.
So My concern is how can I bind my Model with slug rout instead of id. Here is my code:

```html
Route::get('{category}/{article}', function ($category, $article) {
    return view('test',compact('article'));
});
```

```html
RouteServicePovider
Route::bind('category',function($category){
            return $category = \App\Category::where('slug', $category)->firstOrFail();
        });
        Route::bind('article',function($article){
            return \App\Article::where([['category_id',$category->id],['slug',$article],['status',1]])->firstOrFail();
        });
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Try reading your question before posting, or at least reading your question after posting and remove obvious errors. You are asking people to help you for free and you don't even try a little effort asking for it.

Comment: Bro.. I want to fetch article on behalf of category but I'm using slug instead of primary key. my url structure is something like this: domain.com/politics/politics-related-aritcle-on-sulg-url.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which foreign keys the relation uses, so you have to change your model relationship methods like this one:

```
$this->hasMany('App\Article', 'slug', 'article_slug'); 
// replace slug and article_slug with your foreign keys
```

Comment: I customized route key name for category and article model. public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }.... So I think replacing slug and article_slug is not necessary.